# The order of noun-modification patterns in IT

Tags: adjectives, word-order

For example:

The **field Media/Media field** contains all necessary information about the content.
The **Address section/section Address** is located in the lower section of the window.

Does the right variant work both for short and long titles? E.g. "Enter the value into the Default Type of Start field", or "into the field Default Type of Start".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with adjectives.

It is about two different noun-modification patterns.

In *the Media field*, *field* is a common noun, and *Media* serves as a modifier in the noun phrase. It is parallel with huge numbers of expressions such as *the corner house*, and *the television programme*.

In *the field Media*, *Media* is effectively a proper noun (the 'name' of the field), and this is a special form of qualification available only with names, where the qualifying noun identifies the type of object designated by the name. Other examples are *the film 'Frozen'* and *the conductor Simon Rattle*.

As long as you are talking about items regarded as named (which is common in programming, databases, and user interfaces) either construction will work.

In your final question, either is grammatical, but the long name makes the first format confusing unless you pick it out with quotes or italics; so *the "Default Type of Start" field*, works, but the first form as you wrote it is difficult to understand.